# Why doesn't 'for' work inside 'go'?

Tags: clojure

Why calling this function doesn't print anything?

```
(defn test-go-loop []
  (go (for [a (cycle [:a :b :c])]
        (do (println a) (<! (timeout 1000))))))
```

Comment: `for` is lazy *everywhere*, not just in a goroutine. This isn't `go`-specific at all.

Comment: ...that is to say, you'll have the exact same problem with `(defn test-loop [] (for [a (cycle [:a :b :c])] (do (println a) (Thread/sleep 1000))) nil)`

Comment: ...note that the `nil` is important -- if you *returned* the sequence it would get realized by the repl when trying to print it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for` is lazily evaluated, and nothing in your code is *asking* for the result of that `for`. Try `doseq`:

```
(defn test-go-loop []
  (go (doseq [a (cycle [:a :b :c])]
        (println a)
        (<! (timeout 1000)))))
```